# import yyyy/mm/dd date in Matlab6.5 error

Tags: matlab, date

all:

I use the Matlab v6.5 and Matlab v2014b at the same time...
As i look for the help doc of 'datestr', both 'yyyy/mm/dd' and 'yyyy-mm-dd' are support format in v6.5 and v2014b.

But when i use the command below, it makes error in v6.5.

> > N=datenum('2008/12/01') 
> >     ???Error using ==>datevec
> >     2008 is too large to be a month

But when i use the above datenum command in v2014, it gives the right answer...
I'm really confused.
As to the yyyy-mm-dd format, v6.5 makes the same error.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try manually setting the format?

Comment: Hello,Daniel. I'm new to Matlab, and not quite sure what you mean by "manually setting"....but I have try the command as        >>datenum('2008/12/01','yyyy/mm/dd')         but the result is still the same: it works for v2014,but not for v6.5......and what i get from v6.5 is still: 2008 is too large to be a month.....

Comment: MATLAB v6.5 is over 10 years old.  Why are you using it?

Comment: Hello,rayryeng. Thank you for your reply, because i have an old computer which can only run a lower version of Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I used the documentation for 6.5.2 assuming there is no difference). 
When using an old Matlab version, you have to use the corresponding documentation which is available via `doc datenum`. The format you are trying to use is not supported. There is a note in the documentation for datenum which lists the supported formats.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. I've looked BOTH version doc datenum. They all tell me that:"...... N = datenum(S), ...... if S is a string, it must be in one of the date formats 0,1,2,6,13,14,15,16,23(as defined by Datestr), which NOT include the format like yyyy/mm/dd.(yyyy/mm/dd is the format 26). SO it is not the supported formats in the version 2014b. Why do they performed different?

Comment: Please double check this, the documentation for Matlab `2014b` does not contain that sentence. Matlab 2014b uses strings instead of numbers to specify the date! The documentation is available here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014b/matlab/ref/datenum.html

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I'll check your link later(because I cannot access to it rightnow for some reason). I just check the doc datenum from my v2014 on  PC, and make sure that this sentence exist. But we will come back to that later after I check the link......

Comment: Anyway...the reason I want to make the question clear is becasue I have a "yyyy.mm.dd" format csvfile. Since that's not a supported format, I have to change it through other software like UltraEdit. When change the format to "yyyy/mm/dd", it's ok for 2014 but not for v6.5.....And I cannot figure out how to change "yyyy/mm/dd" to "yyyy/dd/mm" which is supported......So can you give me some advice?  Also, now I'm thinking tranform the 'datenum' m-file from v2014 to v6.5....Do you think that's possible?

Comment: Use `textscan` or regular expressions. Simply copying the file will probably fail.